# Android Kotlin : How to set error editext use Data Binding and LiveData

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-livedata, android-databinding, android-viewmodel

I want to validate form login Kotlin with Application Structure Model–view–viewmodel

I used ViewModel with Data Binding and LiveData, Create a variable in the XML file for Two-Way Data

I can validate when empty field but I don't know How to set error for editText when user change EditText invited format or worng characters

> activity_main.xml

```
    <data><variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.validateform.LoginViewModel" />
</data>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay_username"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Username"
        app:errorEnabled="true">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@={viewModel.username}" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay_password"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password"
        app:errorEnabled="true">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@={viewModel.password}" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="@{()-> viewModel.submitLogin()}"
        android:text="Submit"/>
```

> MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var viewModel : LoginViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // Binding
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)

        // ViewModel
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(LoginViewModel::class.java)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        binding.viewModel = viewModel

        initObserver()
    }

    private fun initObserver() {
        viewModel.errorMessage.observe(this, Observer { message ->
            Snackbar.make(binding.btnSubmit, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        })
    }
}
```

> LoginViewModel.kt

```
class LoginViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val username = MutableLiveData()
    val password = MutableLiveData()

    private val _errorMessage = MutableLiveData()
    val errorMessage : LiveData
    get() = _errorMessage

    fun submitLogin() {
        validateForm()
    }

    private fun validateForm() : Boolean {
        var result = true

        if (username.value.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            _errorMessage.value = "User Required"
            result = false
        }

        if (password.value.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            _errorMessage.value = "Password Required"
            result = false
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return error message as a string resource to support localization. Also, you need to create binding adapter for it.

**View model sample**

```kotlin
interface LoginViewModel {
    val errorMessage: LiveData<Int>
}
```

**Binding adapter sample**

```kotlin
@BindingAdapter("error")
internal fun TextInputLayout.setError(@StringRes errorRes: Int) {
    error = errorRes.takeUnless { it == ID_NULL }?.let { resources.getString(it) }
}
```

**Layout**

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/lay_username"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Username"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    bind:error="@{ vm.errorMessage }">

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Note: you don't need flag `app:errorEnabled="true"` if your provide helper text. It main purpose to reserve space for the message.